# Writing and reading files to/from host system on Docker

Tags: docker, filesystems

**Context**:

I have a Java Spring Boot Application which has been deployed to run on a Docker Container. I am using Docker Toolbox to be precise.
The application exposes a few REST API's to upload and download files. The application works fine on Docker i.e. i'm able to upload and download files using API.

**Questions:**

1. In the application I have hard coded the path as something like "C:\SomeFolder". What location is this stored on the Docker container?
2. How do I force the application when running on Docker to use the Host file system instead of Docker's File system?

Answer (score -1):

This is all done by Docker Volumes.

Read more about that in the Docker documentation:

https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Answer (score -1):

> In the application I have hard coded the path as something like "C:\SomeFolder". What location is this stored on the Docker container?

`c:\SomeFolder`, assuming you have a Windows container.  This is the sort of parameter you'd generally set via a command-line option or environment variable, though.

> How do I force the application when running on Docker to use the Host file system instead of Docker's File system?

Use the `docker run -v` option or an equivalent option to mount some directory from the host on that location.  Whatever the contents of that directory are on the host will replace what's in the container at startup time, and after that changes in the host should be reflected in the container and *vice versa*.

If you have an opportunity to rethink this design, there are a number of lurking issues around file ownership and the like.  The easiest way to circumvent these issues are to store data somewhere like a database (which may or may not itself be running in Docker) and use network I/O to send data to and from the container, and store as little as possible in the container filesystem.  `docker run -v` is an excellent way to inject configuration files and get log files out in a typical server-oriented use.